# Is 'lockfileVersion: 2' in package-lock.json from npm 7 compatible with older versions of npm?

Tags: npm, version, lockfile

I was wondering if the new lockfileVersion 2 was backwards compatable with older versions of NPM.

Now since NPM 7 is released, a new package-lock.json file is regenerated to a different structure. From lockfileVersion 1 to 2.

I would be guessing if it was supported, if adding new packages from old npm lockfile to the new one would not be compatible.

Comment: Refer to the _"not yet published docs"_ [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/653769de359b8d24f0d17b8e7e426708f49cadb8/docs/content/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.md#lockfileversion) in the GitHub repo. Under the _"lockfileVersion"_ section it states: _"[lockfileVersion 2]: The lockfile version used by npm v7, which is backwards compatible to v1 lockfiles."_

Answer (score 23):

Yes it is, I tried it myself. And here's a remark from the blog:

> One change to take note of is the new lockfile format, which is backwards compatible with npm 6 users.

source: https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#changes-to-the-lockfile